# Characterization of quasi-coherent modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have been looking for the proof of the following fact with 0 results:
Given a scheme $(S,\mathcal{O})$  a sheave of $\mathcal{O}$-modules is quasi-coherent if and only if for every affine open set $U$ and every affine open set in $U$, i.e $V\subset U$ the restriction map $N(U)\rightarrow N(V)$ extends up to an isomorphism $N(U)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)}\mathcal{O}(V)\simeq N(V)$. Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Can you prove the reverse direction?

Comment: I can´t prove neither, :S

Comment: For the reverse direction, restrict your attention only to distinguished inclusions Spec A_f inside Spec A.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following characterisation of quasi coherent modules found in Qing Liu's book on algebraic geometry: [Theorem 5.1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss5Al.png).

For $ U $ affine open and $ V \subseteq U $ affine open we have
$ (N(U)^\sim)  (V)  = N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(V) $
by definition.

Therefore if $N$ is quasi coherent we have $ N(V) = N \vert_U(V) \cong N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(V) $.

The other way round N(V) $ \cong N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(V) $ for all affine open $V \subseteq U$ implies $ N\vert_U \cong N(U)^\sim $,
because the affine open sets form a base of topologly.

Comment: I don´t see why $(N(U)^\sim)  (V)  = N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(V) $by definition

Comment: I think we can agree that it holds for V principal open. Let $ U = Spec A $, $ f \in A $ and $ V = D(f) =  Spec A_f $. Then $ (N(U)^\sim)(V) = N(U)_f = N(U) \otimes_A A_f =  N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(V)$. The principal open subsets form a base of topology. So the sheaves $ N(U)^\sim $ and  $ N(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}\vert_U $ have to be equal.